# ¿Como Obtener el uso de la memoria ram en Vb.Net?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Buenas amigos de la comunidad, hoy vengo a pedir su ayuda sobre una duda que tengo.

Estoy realizando otra aplicación en Visua Basic.NET y quisiera saber como puedo calcular o obtener el uso de la memoria ram del equipo y mostrarlo en un Progress bar por asi decirlo en tiempo real y que se vaya actualizando cada cierto tiempo, he intentado con un metodo, intente con la clase PerformanceCounter() y use el siguiente codigo:

```
Dim perfRamValue As New Performance("Memory", "Available MBytes") 
ProgressBarRam.Value = perfRamValue.NextValue
```

Pero no me dio el valor correcto en del uso de la ram, tambien intente convertir los "Bytes" recibidos en "MB" pero tampoco funciono... ¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: que fue lo que intentaste?

Comment: Intente con la clase PerformanceCounter() con el siguiente codigo

`Dim perfRamValue As New PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes")

ProgressBarRam.Value = perfRamValue.NextValue

`

Comment: Usa el botón [edit] y agrega toda la info a tu pregunta, inclusive los errores que recibis

Answer (score 0):

Talvez te sea util leer esta documentacion: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo?view=netframework-4.8

La funcion que buscas es My.Computer.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory() que devuelve la cantidad de memoria ram disponible para usar (no la total instalada).

Esto funcionaria en Winforms, no estoy seguro del tipo de framework .net que estas utilizando vos.